# Access VBA Compile error Invalid ParamArray Use

Tags: ms-access, vba

**Context:** In Microsoft Access, I'm trying to call functions and pass parameters, dynamically, using `Application.Run`. My code below works in Excel 2013 but does not work in Access 2013.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub Test()
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled1", "This", "works")
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled2", "This", "works", "too")
    Call MethodDynamically("MethodToBeCalled3", "This", "works", "too", "as well")
End Sub

Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, ParamArray Params() as Variant)
    Application.Run MethodName, Params
End Sub
Public Sub MethodToBeCalled1(Params As Variant)
    Debug.Print Params(0) & " " & Params(1)
End Sub
Public Sub MethodToBeCalled2(Params As Variant)
    Debug.Print Params(0) & " " & Params(1) & " " & Params(2)
End Sub
Public Sub MethodToBeCalled3(Params As Variant)
    Debug.Print Params(0) & " " & Params(1) & " " & Params(2) & " " & Params(3)
End Sub
```

Returns output:

```
This works
This works too
This works too as well
```

**Error:** However in Microsoft Access, the same code gives the error: `Compile error: Invalid ParamArray use`.

Is there a way of adjusting this code for Access VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a ParamArray to another function directly.

Try the following:

```
Public Sub MethodDynamically(MethodName As String, ParamArray Params() as Variant)
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = Params
    Application.Run MethodName, MyArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Great thanks Erik. Out of curiosity, why does this work in Excel and not Access?

Comment: I've noticed multiple weird/buggy things about `Application.Run` in Excel, such as `Application.Run "MyFunction()"` running `MyFunction` twice (causes a runtime error in Access). All I can say is: it shouldn't work afaik.